# ASP.NET and YSlow optimization

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

I'm running a YSlow performance test on my small ASP.NET web project running in an IIS Express. I'm  left back with two items that I think needs optimization.

**1. Add Expires headers**

I need to set expire date on my favicon.ico. How can I do this?

[image]

**2. Primed cache**

When I look in the *statistics* tab, I notice that my HTML is not cached. How can I cache the HTML, so the 6,7K is not downloaded the second time? Why is my favicon requsted in primed cache?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**favicon**:

Add this to your web.config file:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <location path="favicon.ico">
>     <system.webServer>
>       <staticContent>
>         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="90.00:00:00" />
>       </staticContent>
>     </system.webServer>
>   </location>
> </configuration>
> ```

**Html Cache**:

The browser caches a page based on the response headers of the server response.
You should only ask a browser to cache a page if the page contents will not change for a given period of time and an user will revisit this page in the given period.

You an set an cache header using something like:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
```

I recommend that you take a look at the [W3C http cache specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) for a full overview about browser cache.

Also, if you use cache, some browsers will ask your server if the file was modified since the last time they get them (the "[If-Modified-Since" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25)). If the file was not changed, you can respond with the [304 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5).